# Convert capacitive sensor into physical button?

Tags: sensor, button, capacitive

Is it possible to turn a capacitive button in to a protruding mechanical one?

I am thinking something round that sticks to a surface with a capacitive button on it and is essentially just a button version of those tablet stylus tips, and travels straight down when pressed to activate the sensor.

I have a Waterdrop sink water filter that has capacitive buttons to dispense the water and it, **surprise**, gets wet and can't be turned on or off.

It also dispenses boiling water and I'm honestly shocked no one has sued the bejesus out of them for injury yet - the design is straight up dangerous. So many times the steam from the boiling water has made it impossible to turn the boiling water OFF. It's a water dispenser, why would you put capacitive buttons on it?

Comment: Cap touch is starting to become a scourge, they need to stop using it where it doesn't make sense. Anyway, you could probably "hack" into the PCB somehow,  but we'd need some details for that.